# Can I set up a jqgrid treegrid so that it fetches the child data on row open? How?

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid, subgrid

The example treegrid implementation isn't exactly crystal clear. I've got a grid like:

```
  ID  Name    Val
+  1  Foo      45
+  2  Bar      30
```

Which I'm populating from a json object. When you click on the `+`, I want to go to the server and get the data associated with that row's id:

```
  ID  Name    Val
-  1  FooBar   45
   -    Foo    20
   -    Bar    25
+  2  Baz      30
```

Are there any examples that show that more clearly? Also, the ones I'm seeing seem to want you to fetch the whole data set in one go. Or is "adding" and "subtracting" rows a better way to go for this case?

Update: thinking a little further, I don't think the add/subtract method would be good, because it would kill sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably Subgrid is what you need? Look at the [demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and choose "Advanced" and then "Subgrid" of the left tree part. The demo use `subGridUrl` parameter with the server url. If you click for example on "+" from the row with id=6 the request to the `subGridUrl` will send. The request will contain `nd_=1287002219148&id=6` as the additional parameters, where `nd_` with the timestamp are used only to make every url unique and so switch local caching off.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at subgrid. The thing I don't like about it is that it has a whole table, with it's own column structure, whereas, with mine, the children have the same columns, so ideally they'd align. Thanks, though.

Comment: @sprugman: It seems to me if you choose the `width` values in the `subGridModel` corresponds to the `width` values from the `colModel` of you grid you will have the results which you need. Isn't it?

Comment: in theory, yes, but it's quite easy for those kinds of things to become out of sync. As it happens, though, the biz likes the subgrid, so we're off the hook. :)